# Windows 10 system settings panels (Properties, Wifi, etc) are missing letters?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, hp-pavilion

This is a very bizarre problem that might have just started tonight.

I am using Windows 10 on an HP Pavilion Laptop.

When I go into the Properties panel for any file, or (I just learned this) just about any Windows settings-related panel, every 'e' character is missing; it's just blank space. Please see the images below:

[image]
[image]

Perhaps this is related: For months, I get seemingly random pop-up error boxes related to .NET telling me that an HP font is missing. I have neglected it because I was relieved it wasn't a Unity project-killing error (and I am a fool). I apologize for not having pictures of that right now. It would usually come up when using the game engine, Unity.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like something that could be solved by rebuilding the font cache. Unfortunately, I haven’t found reliable instructions.

Comment: Have you tried the standard processes for repairing Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Some system files seem to be corrupted on the disk.

My suggestions:

- Run chkdsk
- Check the SMART info of the disk
  (for example using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
  and in case of problems consider replacing the disk
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and DISM
- If nothing is found, return Windows to a known good state by
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I just ran chkdsk and it found no problems. I'll check one of these other options

Comment: Perform a in-place repair in that case.  Chkdsk doesn’t really do anything helpful in a case like this.

Comment: Checking the SMART data is important.